# How test classes get reference of source classes in junit test?

Tags: java, junit

Junit test classes reside in totally different target folders, but while running test cases how is it possible for test class to get reference to the source classes?

Comment: Are you asking *how* it does something or *how to make it do* something? I am a little confused.

Comment: How is it possible for your classes to get a reference to classes defined in a 3rd party library (like JUnit for example)? Well, it's exactly the same here.

Comment: there's a path passed as an argument to the jvm, the directory holding the test classes and the directory holding the classes being tested are both in the path. the classloader looks in the path to find the classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test framework makes use of the *classpath* feature of a JVM. The classpath indicates where the program running the tests should find the classes it needs. The environment (your IDE, for example) sets the classpath to search in both the location of your test classes and the location of the classes you are testing. It will probably set the classpath to search in the location of your test classes *and then* search in the location of the classes being tested.